# How to run specific junit tests at run time

Tags: java, junit4

I'm trying to figure out a good solution to having specific unit tests run with certain runtime configurations.  For example:

```
public class TestClassAlpha() {

    @setup 
    public void setup() {
    }

    @After 
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    @Test
    @<only run in particular env>
    public void testA() {
        //whatever A
    }

    //always run below test no mater what env
    @Test
    public void testB() {
        //whatever B 
    }

}
```

I am contemplating a custom annotation or custom rule perhaps, but i thought this has to be a question that comes up frequently as running tests in certain conditions (envs) is a very valid scenario.   I did some limited searching within stack, and I didn't find anything that really that helped solidify either way.

Answer (score 1):

This [post](http://www.mikereedell.com/2011/12/15/JUnit-Conditional-Ignore-Using-Rules.html) shows you exactly what you require.

You should Write a Custom `TestRule` and an annotation to mark the condition.